# How can we use app engine users API (java) with other google APIs to get users' profile pictures?

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail, google-api, google-plus, google-api-java-client

With app engine Users API (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/), it is very easy to setup an account system.

But how do we get users' profile pictures from their Gmail or Google Plus accounts?

Answer (score 2):

To get a user's profile picture from Google+ you need to use G+ API which requires using OAuth2.

Here is a very simple example how you can get a person's profile info (including profile picture) : https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get?hl=en#examples

Hope this will help you :)